# Any behavior difference from these slightly different state drawables?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-selector

**Q1)** Looking at original `ListView` state drawable for `listSelector` we have something like this (I stripped some code to simplify the example):

```
<selector>
    <item android:drawable="<TRANSPARENT>" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_1>" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_1>" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_2>" android:state_focused="true"/>
</selector>
```

But I've been doing it like this on my app:

```
<selector>
    <item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_2>" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_1>" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="<TRANSPARENT>" />
</selector>
```

Which seems to produce the same result and it's much more simple. Do you notice any situation where the first one will work better than my own version? I just want to make sure I'm not missing something important cause I pefer to keep my code as short as possible...

**Q2)** I see many state drawables with `<item android:drawable="<TRANSPARENT>" android:state_window_focused="false"/>` as the top item but I can't understand why is it needed. The `state_window_focused` always confused me a bit... Is it really necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to put this into an answer, even though I'm not sure about it, but that's what I think:

**I'll start with Q2:**

`state_window_focused` corresponds to the default behaviour ("window" visible, but unfocused) and I think it's used just to point out the default (`TRANSPARENT`).

**About Q1:**

`DRAWABLE2` will be visualised in both cases and under the same conditions - focused and unpressed, because:

*First case:*

```
<item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_2>" android:state_focused="true"/>
```

*Second case:*

```
`<item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_2>" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>`
```

We have the D2 while focused, but in your case also while unpressed.

`DRAWABLE1` will be visible only while pressed in each and every case. The difference is that in the first case, the two additional states are given too `android:state_focused="true/false"`, which doesn't make any sense, so the two lines in Case 1 can be shrunk to one (exactly the one you have):

```
<item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_1>"  android:state_pressed="true"/>
```

So, to sum things up:

Case 1 - you have :

```
<selector>
    <item android:drawable="<TRANSPARENT>" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_1>" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_1>" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_2>" android:state_focused="true"/>
</selector>
```

Which is equivalen to:

```
<selector>
    <item android:drawable="<TRANSPARENT>" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_1>"  android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_2>"  android:state_focused="true"/>
</selector>
```

And your case (case 2), for comparison:

```
<selector>
    <item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_2>" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="<DRAWABLE_1>" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="<TRANSPARENT>" />
</selector>
```

**The only difference I can see so far, is that in the first case, the `DRAWABLE2` will be shown only when focused (no matter if pressed or not), but in your case it has to be also unpressed and that's the only condition which is different.**